# Why ExpressJS ignore Access-Control-Allow-Origin settings?

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, cors

I'm working on an Angular project.
I use ExpressJS and Mongoose for API.

When I implement requests from Angular to ExpressJS I've CORS error. But When I use Postman to reproduce client side, there is no error.

My angular app is running on httpS://localhost:4200
ExpressJS server API is on : http://localhost:3000
is it a matter if Origin is secured with SSL ? If it is, how can I disable SSL part from Angular ?

Angular part:
**login.service.ts**

```
getUser(email: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>('http://localhost:3000/login', {email: email}, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((user: User) => {
        this.currentUser = user
      })
    );
  }
```

ExpressJS part:
**app.js**

```
const cors = require('cors')
[...]
var allowCrossDomain = {
  "origin": "*",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  "preflightContinue": false
}
app.use(cors(allowCrossDomain))

router.head("/login", cors(), (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(204);
});
router.post('/login', cors(allowCrossDomain), async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const user = await User.login(req.body)
    res.json(user)
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ error: err.message || err.toString() });
  }
});
```

Do you have any idea, why it doesn't works ?
I also created a route like :

```
router.get('/test', cors(allowCrossDomain), (req, res) => { res.json({message: "it works"}) })
```

And when I open this url in a browser I can see in response header :
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Thanks for help.

Answer (score -1):

Finally found the answer.
In angular.json I had to define a proxy :

```
{
...
"proxyConfig": {
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3000",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
    }
  }
...
}
```